# 2 or more months view or even a year view in FullCalendar?

Tags: fullcalendar

Is there any way to set up [fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) to display a given number of months, or even a full year?

Comment: Answer is yes.  You need to be a little more specific, then someone or myself will try to help.

Comment: @Khnle: Would like to show June, July, August 2010 in a row or a column... Would also be nice to select a time period at the end of June going into July.

Comment: OK, is this supposed to be a web app? desktop app?  Are you using jQuery, extjs or just plain javascript?  Or you don't want javascript, just plain html and css.  Or maybe this has nothing with web app at all, and it's supposed to be a linux app?  Those kinds of details are knind of needed.

Comment: Definitely a web app using jQuery being able to populate the calendar on page load, but the user would also select a number of dates to add a particular event. The details of the event would be submitted to the server using AJAX and saved to a database but displayed on the calendar as well.

Comment: Your not the only one! See [issue 871](http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=871).

Answer (score 2):

you can try my fork which has this feature :

https://github.com/tpruvot/fullcalendar
http://epsy.ath.cx/fullcalendar-yearview/demos/year.html